# how to lazy load modules from a separate application

Tags: angular

I'm implementing a super application in angular 4 which would load child application modules (components and routes). The child application is hosted on http://child-application-url. How can I lazy load the child module in my super application?

{
path: 'child-module-path',
loadChildren: 'http://child-application-url/main.js#ChildModule'
}

These are my dependencies

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular-redux/store": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^6.0.1",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^0.0.3",
    "@types/hammerjs": "^2.0.34",
    "body-parser": "^1.17.1",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "express": "^4.15.2",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "redux": "^3.6.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
    "karma": "~1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.0",
    "ts-node": "~2.0.0",
    "tslint": "~4.5.0",
    "typescript": "~2.2.0"
  }
```

Child application:

ng new child-app

Create a new feature module 'child' and lazy load it in the child-app as

`{
  path: 'module1',
  loadChildren: 'app/child/child.module#ChildModule',
}`

ng build and run on port 4202 on node server

Super application:

ng new super-app

Having an issue when trying to load the child-app's module lazily

`{
path: 'child-module-path',
loadChildren: 'http://child-application-url/main.js#ChildModule'
}`

Comment: Can you give more details? You code?

Comment: @wannadream ... I have updated the description with details

Comment: I do not believe your code will work but you can exploit more in source code. https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/5293794316cc1b0f57d5d88b3fefdf6ae29d0d97/packages/router/src/router_config_loader.ts
https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/a4de214e2be5048f1261d043cc467a5ecaa5c909/tools/public_api_guard/core/core.d.ts

Comment: @user2836528 did you resolve the problem?

Comment: What is the "issue" you're having? Are you getting an error? Have you been able to resolve this?